# Why is udisksctl loop-setup so slow?

Tags: linux

### udisksctl

```
$ time udisksctl loop-setup -f Windows.iso                                       
Mapped file Windows.iso as /dev/loop0.

real    3m0.784s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.010s
```

### losetup

```
# time losetup -f Windows.iso

real    0m0.009s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.004s
```

I need to use `udisksctl` because no root is required for it. However, my gripe with it is that compared to `losetup` it's extremely slow. I do want to note however that `udisksctl` rarely mounts it straight away like `losetup` does; however I don't know why. The `mount` command with the `-o loop` option is also very fast like `losetup`.

I did an `strace` on the `udisksctl` and it seems to be spending pretty much all that time on polling as I would have guessed based on the `time` measurement.

```
poll([{fd=8, events=POLLIN}], 1, -1)    = 1 ([{fd=8, revents=POLLIN}])
read(8, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16)         = 8
poll([{fd=8, events=POLLIN}], 1, -1
```

Is there anyway I can speed it up or at least some other non-root tool I can use? Also, are other people experiencing similar results?